# bootstrap media bottom not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the [media bottom bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media-default) component but the text is top aligned despite adding the `media-bottom` class. Is this component broken or something. Any clean workaround?

Thanks

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2yrrf6zx/2/

HTML code:

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left media-bottom">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object pull-left" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <p>Title</p>
    <h4 class="media-heading">text</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add "media-bottom" class to the div with "media-body" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the `media-bottom` on the image and not on the text. If you use the following HTML, it should work as expected:

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object pull-left" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body media-bottom">
    <p>Title</p>
    <h4 class="media-heading">text</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yrrf6zx/4/)

Comment: Yeah this works. Thanks. It's weird because I copied the html code from the bootstrap page.

Comment: You were trying to `media-bottom` an image that was already the size of the div. There was nothing to `bottom` (or `top` for that matter). If the height of the div was greater than the height of the image, you would be able to `media-bottom` it. Don't forget to accept (and maybe press the up-arrow) this answer!